# Nan::ObjectWrap to Napi::Object Wrap can't access to properties in JavaScript

Tags: c++, node.js

I have modify a code from Nan to Napi (C++ addon). This code use the ObjectWrap class.
Before with Nan, when i tried to obtain the properties of the object returned by the node-addon it works.

```
console.log(Object.keys(result)); 
[ 'bool', 'string', 'int', 'float', 'vtype' ]
```

Now, with Napi, when i try the same command i get:

```
[]
```

But the access to the properties continues to work:

```
console.log(result.bool);
false
```

My init code:

```
Napi::Object JSVariant::Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports)
{
    Napi::HandleScope scope(env);
    Napi::Function ctor = DefineClass(env, "JSVariant", {InstanceAccessor("vtype", &JSVariant::GetVTypeValue, &JSVariant::SetVTypeValue), InstanceAccessor("float", &JSVariant::GetFltValue, &JSVariant::SetFltValue), InstanceAccessor("int", &JSVariant::GetIntValue, &JSVariant::SetIntValue), InstanceAccessor("string", &JSVariant::GetStringValue, &JSVariant::SetStringValue), InstanceAccessor("bool", &JSVariant::GetBoolValue, &JSVariant::SetBoolValue)});

    constructor = Napi::Persistent(ctor);
    constructor.SuppressDestruct();
    exports.Set("JSVariant", ctor);
    return exports;
}
```

Is there a way to obtain the Nan result with Napi ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how does your original Nan code look, but

- `Object.keys` does not work with properties from the `prototype` object which is what you are doing
- `InstanceAccessor` has an optional fourth argument taking a `napi_propety_attributes` value which you must set to `napi_enumerable` for the property to be visible - but it will be so only in `Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj))`